# Using RestTemplate in Spring Boot Spock specification with customized Jackson

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spock, spring-test-mvc

I have a Spring Boot app that's using a customized Jackson ObjectMapper, and I would like to use the same customized mapper during testing. I used spring boot's method of automatically registering Module Beans, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    public Module jodaMoneyJackson() {
        SimpleModule jodaMoneyModule = new SimpleModule();

        jodaMoneyModule.addDeserializer(Money.class, new JsonDeserializer<Money>() {
            @Override
            public Money deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                return Money.parse(p.getText());
            }
        });

        jodaMoneyModule.addSerializer(Money.class, new ToStringSerializer());

        return jodaMoneyModule;
    }

    @Bean public Module googleGuavaJackson() {
        return new GuavaModule();
    }
}
```

In my spock tests I would like RestTemplate to use the "built-in" Jackson object mapper that automatically registers the custom modules. In the actual app it seems like that's just used automatically, but not in my test classes. How can I make it work for my tests?

Here's roughly what my test spec looks like:

```
@WebIntegrationTest
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader, classes = MyApplication)
class SomeTestSpec extends Specification {

    def restTemplate = new RestTemplate()        

    def "test my controller"() {
        given:
        Money expectedTotal = Money.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, 100.00)
        String request = this.class.classLoader.getResource("testInput.json").text

        when:
        def response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/test", request, SomeClass)

        then:
        response.total == expectedTotal
    }
}
```

I always get a 400 Bad Request response with this, and when debugging I can see that it's because internally the serialization/deserialization isn't using my custom module.

As as workaround I have instantiated my own object mapper and am registering the modules manually, then calling mapper.readValue() with a String response from RestTemplate, but it feels like there should be a better way. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Spock's Spring support, provided by `spock-spring`, you can have the `ObjectMapper` injected into your test specification:

```
@WebIntegrationTest
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader, classes = MyApplication)
class SomeTestSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper

}
```

Comment: What's the best way to make RestTemplate use that mapper internally?

Comment: Create a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` using the `ObjectMapper` and configure your `RestTemplate` to use the converter